# Addition of a mysql value in perl using placeholders

Tags: mysql, perl, placeholder

I want to add a value to a mysql value already present in the database. I know that you can do this by:

```
 my $sql1 =qq(UPDATE genotype SET Tally=Tally+10);
```

However, I want the '+10' to be a placeholder, as the value will vary depending upon which iteration of a for loop the program is in. I have written the following, however it does not work:

```
my $sql1 =qq(UPDATE genotype SET Tally=Tally + ?);
my $sth1 = $dbh_m-> prepare($sql1);

$sth1->execute($ParentTally);
```

Is it possible to use a placeholder here? I had alternatively written:

```
my $sql5 =qq(SELECT Tally FROM genotype);
my $sth5 = $dbh_m-> prepare($sql5); 

$sth5->execute();
my $newTally;

while (my $ChosenTally = $sth5 ->fetch){
    for my $field (@$ChosenTally){
        $newTally=$field;
    }
}

$newTally+=$ParentTally;


my $sql6 =qq(UPDATE genotype SET Tally= ?);
my $sth6 = $dbh_m-> prepare($sql6); 

$sth6->execute($newTally);
```

The above code does work, however I want to reduce the number of connections my program has to the database if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the value using [`bind_param`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#bind_param) prior to query execution:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $query_with_placeholder );

for my $int ( 1 .. 10 ) {
    $sth->bind_param(1, $int, SQL_INTEGER );
    $sth->execute;
}
```

Alternatively, just pass `$int`  to `execute` :

```
$sth->execute( $_ ) for 1 .. 10 ;
```

Comment: Thank you, however I still don't understand how I can get it to add the number to the value already present in the database, when I try this it doesn't add to the value already present. (e.g database has value 10, ParentTally is value 10, so I want the new total value in the database to be 20)